# How to open a modal dialog popup from an iframe (sharepoint hosted app, (app part))) in the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, iframe

so I developed this sharepoint hosted app with an app part which renders a calendar, when they click on a day it must open a modal popup with an url that I already have.

I will paste the error at the end.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<!-- Core CSS File. The CSS code needed to make eventCalendar works -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/eventCalendar.css">

<!-- Theme CSS file: it makes eventCalendar nicer -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/eventCalendar_theme_responsive.css">
```

Here is the JS

```
var SPHostUrl;
var SPAppWebUrl;
var ListaEventos;
var Categoria;
var ready = false;
var $events = [];

// this function is executed when the page has finished loading. It performs two tasks:
//    1. It extracts the parameters from the url
//    2. It loads the request executor script from the host web
$(document).ready(function () {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var param = params[i].split("=");
        switch (param[0]) {
            case "SPAppWebUrl":
                SPAppWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
            case "SPHostUrl":
                SPHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
            case "TituloListaEventos":
                TituloListaEventos = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
            case "Categoria":
                Categoria = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
            case "NombreListaEventos":
                NombreListaEventos = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                break;
        }
    }

    // load the executor script, once completed set the ready variable to true so that
    // we can easily identify if the script has been loaded
    $.getScript(SPHostUrl + "/_Layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", function (data) {
        ready = true;
        getItems();
        ShowServerInformation();
    });


    var sub = SPHostUrl.substring(0, SPHostUrl.lastIndexOf('/'))
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + sub + '/Style%20Library/SPCCapatech/SPCCapatech.css">');
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + sub + '/Style%20Library/SPCCapatech/colors.css">');
});

function ShowServerInformation() {

    var options = {
        url: "/_layouts/Viewlsts.aspx&IsDlg=1",
        tite: 'Server Information',
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true,
        width: 430,
        height: 230
    };
    parent.SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    return false;

}
```

whenthe showserverinformation function is executed I get this error:

```
 Permission denied to access property "SP"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard security restriction. Otherwise any IFRAME JavaScript could execute anything it wants in the parent window.

In order to manipulate the parent window you have to use [HTML 5 Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

1. Execute window.postMessage() from your IFRAME to send "an order" to the parent window.
2. Process this message in the parent window and create the modal window as the reaction to this message.